# Monitoring traffice from an internet enabled printer

Tags: wireless-networking, wireshark, network-monitoring

I have a WiFi internet enabled printer that can grab content from the web. I want to use something like Fiddler or Wireshark to view the traffic it's sending and receiving. Is possible? How would I go about accomplishing this?

Comment: Yes it's possible. Wireshark and a (WiFi) network adapter with [promiscuous mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promiscuous_mode) should do it. What have you tried arelady? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I've only run wireshark a few times monitoring local traffic and never a remote service. I'll look into what promiscuous mode is. Next I suppose I'll need some way to tell wireshark to look for a particular source address?

Comment: so it sounds like I need the printer's network adapter set to promiscuous mode, correct? I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/299523/23133 - Read the links and then, if needed, come back with specific questions. Short form: Step 1) Determine if your PC WiFi adapter supports promiscuous mode. 2) Turn it on. 3) Sniff WiFi traffic of all devices on the network. 4) Profit. ;)